# Create Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

I got this Run-time error '1004':- This command requires at least two rows of source data. You cannot use the command on a selection in only one row. Try the following: If you're using an advanced filter, select a range of cells that contains at least two rows of data. Then click the Advanced Filter command again. If you're creating a PivotTable report or PivotChart report, type a [it stops here]

I got the aforementioned error at:-

```
pvc.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("TABLE").Range("A1"), _
TableName:="INFO", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

I'm trying to run this code:-

```
Sub CreateTable()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim pvc As PivotCache
 lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Database", RefersTo:="=DATA!$G$1:$K$" & lastRow
Set pvc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Database", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
pvc.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("TABLE").Range("A1"), _
TableName:="INFO", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
    Sheets("TABLE").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").PivotFields("MODEL")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").PivotFields("TYPE")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "INFO").PivotFields("GRADE"), "Sum of GRADE", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "INFO").PivotFields("SIZE"), "Sum of SIZE", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "INFO").PivotFields("QTY"), "Sum of QTY", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").PivotFields("MODEL")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").PivotFields("TYPE")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").PivotFields("Sum of GRADE")
        .Orientation = xlPINFOField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").PivotFields("Sum of SIZE")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").CompactLayoutColumnHeader = "MODEL"
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "SIZE"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("INFO").PivotFields("GRADE").Caption = "GRADE"
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("B:BB").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("C1").Select
End Sub
```

Pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the reason that this error occurs is due to the fourth row:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
```

by the look of this, you are finding the last row of data in your "DATA" sheet by looking in column 6. Now if we look what you are combining this with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Database", RefersTo:="=DATA!$G$1:$K$" & lastRow
```

Now, if your source data is in cells G1:K** then:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
```

will always return 1 unless you have data in column 6, but from the line above, it seems that your data starts in column 7 ("G"). Therefore, to get this to work you have to change the fourth row to:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
```